# In a React Input, how do I convert each letter typed to a capital, but you can type in middle without cursor jumping to end on each keypress?

Tags: reactjs

I've seen lots of asks and no real solutions that have worked.
I've got a React Input:

```
<input
  type="text"
  onChange={onChangeHandler}
  value={value}
/>
```

and an onChange handler:

```
const onChangeHandler = event => {
  setStateValue(event.target.value.toUpperCase());
}
```

Hey, it works at making everything I type in CAPS, but if I were to click in the middle of the input to try and type in the middle, after a single key press, it jumps the cursor to the end, which is really annoying.

I'm using Hooks.

Is what I want even doable, or are we just locked into a corner by React and the way it's made to work?

I've seen some extremely long and convoluted looking solutions, as well as trying to track cursor and restore position, but I couldn't get it to work.

This should be something simple to do, but from what I've read, it seems like FB's got their expected behaviour locked in and aren't flexible on making this work simply.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please replace onChangeHandler() with:

  const onChangeHandler = e => {
    var start = e.target.selectionStart;
    var end = e.target.selectionEnd;
    e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    e.target.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    setStateValue(e.target.value.toUpperCase());
  };
```